# Receive method in JMS waiting for messages

Tags: spring, jms, message

I want a method to browse all messages from a messsage queue and can send it to another queue using jmstemplate with using Websphere queues(NOT MQ). I have tried using receive and it is able to retrieve all the messages from the queue but it is still waiting for another message. And the messages are being lost. It must be in a transaction

The Code I have Tried:

**String message = (String) jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert();

```
System.out.print(message);

while ((message  =  (String) jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert()) != null) {

      messages.add(message);

}
 return messages;
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JMStemplate` should be used for only  synchronous read or sending message. For asychronous read use one of the listener implementation. Read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-mdp)